# Finding the size of certain elements in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sizeof

how can I find the size of determined members of an array. For example, I declared my array with this:

```
string myStrArray[200] = {
    "My first string",
    "My second string",
    "My last string"
}
```

In this code, there are 197 unused elements (or I understand that so). I want to find this array's certain elements (3 elements) by a code such as **sizeof()**. How can I do that?

Comment: All the elements are used, only the last 197 are empty.

Comment: What do you want, the indices of these elements? Or can one assume that they will always be the first ones?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. However, you can zero the array first then count the number of non-zero elements but this would require the array to contain `string*` rather than `string`.

You could use a vector instead, for example:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.reserve(200); // Allocate space for 200
v.push_back("My first string");
v.push_back("My second string");
v.push_back("My last string");
v.size(); // Returns 3
```

Comment: The first line is wrong. No need for `new` on the RHS. And calling a variable `vector` is asking for trouble!

Comment: @juanchopanza You are correct. Thanks for pointing that out. Copy and paste fail.

Comment: @CharlesBailey You are correct. As I mentioned above, this was a copy and paste fail but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes You are correct. I have clarified that portion of the answer to say it does not answer that part of the original question.

Comment: You can prealocate a `std::vector` either with `v.reserve(n)` or directly from one of its constructors, `vector v(n)`.

Comment: @akton you could use the `reserve` function. When you write `v.reserve( 200 );` it allocates space to hold 200 `string`s

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes Thanks for that. I was not aware of that function. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way (at least in C++, what I know) to read out how many elements in array is determined. You have to do it by your own variable (increment it when you "add" elements and decrement when "delete"). You can also use std::vector. vector.size() returns the size of the vector.

Comment: There are ways. You just check for elements that are equal or not equal to `""`.

Comment: It works but only on newly created array. If it was edited many times, this metod is not the best. Except of it, it has linear complexity.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that all of the non-empty strings are at the beginning, then you can use `std::find`:

```
int n = std::find(myStrArray, myStrArray + 200, "") - myStrArray;
```

Actually, you could use `std::lower_bound`, which is a binary search, and so would be more efficient than `std::find`.  But you'd need a fancy comparison function.  One that returns true if the lhs is non-empty and the rhs is empty, false otherwise.

If the non-empty elements are sparsely distributed, you will want to use `std::count`:

```
int n = 200 - std::count(myStrArray, myStrArray + 200, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use sizeof() to find out how many elements are "filled" in the array, you are storing std::string's in the array (I assume atleast) and all elements will be of the same size (because std::string's do not change size after initialization). No objects change size in C++ actually at least not according to sizeof(); sizeof() will always return the same number for a type because it returns the size of the static type.

If you consider a position in the array to be "filled" when the string does not equal to "", then you can use the following code to count the number of strings:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    if (!myStrArray[i].empty()) ++count;
```

I would recommend using a std::vector<> instead though (that is almost always a better idea):

```
std::vector<std::string> my_strings = { "a", "b" }; // requires C++11 in C++03 use push_back()
std::cout << "Number of strings: " << my_strings.size() << std::endl;
```